# Rally SDK2.0 RC3 Query

Tags: filter, rally, datastore

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to retrieve a set of stories using a tag name (TagName) as a filter. I have tried the following, but it always returns an empty store (the alert at the bottom returns []). Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
    var storyStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
        model: "User Story",
        fetch: true,
        filters: [
            {
                property: 'Tags.Name',
                operator: '=',
                value: 'TagName'
            }
        ]
    });

    storyStore.load({
        callback: function(records, operation) {
            if(!operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                //process records
            }
        }
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(storyStore.getRecords()));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the asynchronous nature of the store.load call.  Your store and filters look totally right.  Try putting your alert inside of the if statement within your callback.  I bet you'll find there is data in there then:

```
 storyStore.load({
    callback: function(records, operation) {
        if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(storyStore.getRecords()));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried what you said but the alert inside the callback was never triggered. I toyed around with it a bit and noticed that trying to call the storyStore object within the callback was breaking the call. Then I had that "aha!" moment and realized I should be calling the "records" object declared in the function parameters for the callback. Rookie mistake :) Unfortunately the stringify function doesn't work like it did for SDK 1.x so I'll have to figure out how to rifle through the contents of the object using sdk 2.0. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, the records are instances of Ext.data.Model so you will get a ton of extra data in there.  If you want the raw info from each record you can get it like this: records[0].getData()